# How to wrap a SAP control with a DIV?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have this code, but on small screens, the `center` Label will not show text ellipsis.

```
new sap.m.HBox({
    items: [
        new sap.m.Label({
            text: 'start', 
            width: '100px',
            layoutData: new sap.m.FlexItemData({
                growFactor: 0
            })
        }),
        new sap.m.Label({
            text: 'center',
            width: '100%',
            layoutData: new sap.m.FlexItemData({
                growFactor: 1
            })
        }),
        new sap.m.Label({
            text: 'end', 
            width: '100px',
            layoutData: new sap.m.FlexItemData({
                growFactor: 0
            })
        })
    ]
})
```

So, what I want to do is, wrap the `center` Label with a HTML `div` element and set `style="display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;"` on it to get the text ellipsis working. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got it. :)

```
new sap.m.HBox({
    items: [
        new sap.m.Label({
            text: 'start', 
            width: '100px',
            layoutData: new sap.m.FlexItemData({
                growFactor: 0
            })
        }),
        new sap.m.Panel({
            backgroundDesign: sap.m.BackgroundDesign.Transparent,
            content: new sap.m.Label({
                text: 'center center center center center center center center',
                wrapping: true,
                maxLines: 1,
                layoutData: new FlexItemData({
                    growFactor: 1
                })
            })
        }).addStyleClass('sapUiNoContentPadding fixFlexOverflow'),
        new sap.m.Label({
            text: 'end', 
            width: '100px',
            layoutData: new sap.m.FlexItemData({
                growFactor: 0
            })
        })
    ]
})
```

CSS

```
.fixFlexOverflow {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```